What is the query to fetch user details by email in Content Hub
I have created a user in Content Hub with Username as test@test.com. For its Email property, I have set the same value i.e., test@test.com
Assuming that there could be multiple users with same Username and same Email, I would like to fetch all the users by passing email as parameter.
The email can be a user's Username or Email or both.
I'm using Postman to test the queries.
When I execute this query, the output is as expected. There is only one returned result and the identifier is that of the User's.
{{Hostname}}/api/entities/query?query=Definition.Name=='User' AND String('Username')=='test@test.com'

But, when I execute this query, there is an output with 1 returned result, but the identifier is that of User Profile, which is not desired. I'm expecting the User Identifier in results and not the User Profile details.
{{Hostname}}/api/entities/query?query=String('Email')=='test@test.com'

I also tried this, which returns no results:
{{Hostname}}/api/entities/query?query=Definition.Name=='User' AND String('Email')=='test@test.com'

How can I fetch the User's details (and not User Profile) by passing email as the parameter.
UPDATE:
Here is the result, when I hit the UserToUserProfile URL


In order to fetch the User by email, you will need to run two queries as below.

Search for the email property on the UserProfile entity definition with the query as below.

/api/entities/query?query=Definition.Name=='M.UserProfile' AND String('Email')=='{Email_Address}'

Since email property exist on M.UserProfile entity, hence we first need to  get the user profile.

Once the user profile is retrieved, we can fetch the User by reading UserToUserProfile relation in the above api response.


This relation contains the User associated with the user profile. Using this way we can fetch the user details using email in Content Hub.
Moreover, in case you are using Web SDK, you can use following snippet to fetch user by email.
using Stylelabs.M.Base.Querying;
using Stylelabs.M.Base.Querying.Linq;
using Stylelabs.M.Framework.Essentials.LoadConfigurations;
using Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Contracts.Base;
using Stylelabs.M.Sdk.WebClient;
using Stylelabs.M.Sdk.WebClient.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

string email = "{{EmailAddress}}";
var query = Query.CreateQuery(entities =>
            from e in entities
            where e.DefinitionName == "M.UserProfile"
            && e.Property("Email") == email
            select e);
           
var queryResult = await MClient.Querying.SingleAsync(query, EntityLoadConfiguration.Full);
var userProfileRelation = await queryResult.GetRelationAsync<IChildToOneParentRelation>("UserToUserProfile");
if (userProfileRelation != null)
{
   var userProfileId = userProfileRelation.GetId();
   var user = await MClient.Entities.GetAsync(userProfileId.Value, EntityLoadConfiguration.Full);
}

Hope this helps!!!

Thank you. It will be 3 queries. The first will be get list of "UserToUserProfile" URLs. The Second, will be hitting this URL to get another URL which will be like "/api/entities/1001", where 1001 is the User ID. Then the Third query of this URL where finally I can see the User Identifier. Is that correct. There should be a better way, I'm assuming!

@sukesh No just you need to to read UserToUserProfile  relation value /api/entities/12799080/relations/UserToUserProfile, where 12799080 is the user profile id. This is one to one mapping between user and user profile, so there will no list. Reading the href value inside above url would give you all the properties of User. Hope this helps!!!

Moreover, this could all be done in 2 line of code in case you are using Web SDK..But since you are using Rest api, therefore this will be the only way.

Sorry I did not understand your comment. Reading the URL gives another set of URLs and not the details. I have posted the snap in question. Could you please have a look. Thank you

ya you need to read the href value under the parent object...This will return the all the properties of the User.

@sukesh I have uploaded the code snippet required to get the user by email in case you are using Web SDK. With the sdk, you can effectively read the relation values. Hope that helps!!!

Thank you for the query. I guess entities has be declared first before passing into the query. Is that correct, if so, could you please let me know how to do that.

@sukesh I have included the namespaces to be included. This is a LINQ query. You can find details on the same here https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/cloud-dev/linq-queries-1286073.html#system-properties. Hope this helps!!!
